# Zero fill numbers in Djangos URLconf

Tags: python, regex, django, url

In the [documentation of Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#example) is an example pattern for an URL of an article:

```
(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
```

So, only `2011/05/23/` will match, but not `2011/5/23/`

In another part of the docs, where the [permalinks decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink) is  explained, the pattern is

```
(r'/archive/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$', archive_view)
```

And the code for creating a permalink

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('archive_view', (), {
        'year': self.created.year,
        'month': self.created.month,
        'day': self.created.day})
```

In particular, month has changed from `\d{2}` to `\d{1,2}`, so `2011/05/23/` and `2011/5/23/` will now both match; the `get_absolute_url` method will create the second link, without leading zero.

To create a permalink for the first regex (`\d{2}`), I could write `str(self.created.month).zfill(2)` in the method, but this seems a bit cumbersome and too redundant (if I change the URLconf, I will need to change the `get_absolute_url` method, too) to me.

Additionally, we have now multiple urls which all display the same content (`2011/05/03/`, `2011/5/03/`, `2011/05/3/`, etc.), could that be a problem, e.g. for search engines? At least it can result in inconsistent urls.

Is there a (simple) way to redirect all urls to the zero filled ones (`2011/5/3/` › `2011/05/03/`) and also automatically always build them zerofilled, so I don't need to mess around in methods like `get_absolute_url` with str() and zfill and can just pass the number?

Comment: Yes you would take an SEO hit for having to urls point to the same page/data, other than telling you that I cant really help sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way that I know of to get Django to automatically zero fill numbers passed in as parameters to a URL, other than the way you are already doing it.

You could relax the regex to not require the zero, as you described, which would create a duplicate content issue. However, @Matt fails to consider that the content has to actually be exposed at both URLs for search engines to consider it duplicate. More likely than not, all URLs on your site would be composed from either `reverse` (or `models.permalink` decorator around `get_absolute_url`) or the `{% url %}` template tag. Therefore, all the URLs would be the same format, i.e. without zeros, and the zero-version would never even been seen by search engines.

Additionally, you can make use of the canonical tag to let search engines know that the content is not duplicate, but merely available through multiple URLs.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.com/archive/2011/5/3/" />
```

So search engines are nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Since there seems to be no one else who knows a way to accomplish this, I will need to accept this and use optional zeros. Still confusing why the official docs are inconsistent and use different regex in different examples.

Comment: My guess is that it's a simple oversight. The documentation is handled just like the rest of the Django codebase. There's many cooks in the kitchen, so you end up with slight inconsistencies here and there. If you ever think there's an issue with the documentation, you can submit a ticket for it, just as you would for a bug in Django itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the `url.py` remove the unnecessary link containing the views that does not exist.